# Actualizar input sin recargar página con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo un input que trae el valor de mi base de datos, el detalle es que quiero que al insertar otro valor en mi base de datos el input cambie y se actualice sin necesidad de recargar la página, les adjunto mi código javascrip:

```
function enviar(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: 'datos.php',
      success: function(d){
        console.log('!Eureka!');
        $("#temp").val(d);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Y aquí dejo mi input:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="temp" id="temp" onblur="enviar();">
```

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué hace tu código actualmente? ¿Por qué lo pusiste en el `onblur`?

Comment: mi código me trae el último valor en mi base de datos, en eso funciona correctamente, lo que necesito es que al actualizar la base de datos se actualice el input para que me traiga el nuevo dato sin necesidad de recargar la página

Comment: Depende de la complejidad de tu proyecto. Si tienes un numero limitado y bien conocido de usuarios podrías usar el método Pooling, que consiste en usar un setInterval para hacer peticiones al servidor cada X segundos. Si tienes un numero mayor de usuarios podrías usar Long Pooling; una mejora de la tecnica anterior, que consiste en usar promesas del lado de JavaScript; usas un setInterval y una promesa dentro de una funcion asincorna que se quede esperando hasta que el servidor responda. Si necesitas respuesta inmediata entonces si necesitas webSockets. Suerte.

Answer (score -1):

Pero primero hay que entender que las paginas funcionan de manera síncrona es decir que el el cliente es el que hace la solicitud y recibe una respuesta del lado del servidor.

Una de las formas en la que el servidor pueda tener un cambio y este se refleje en el cliente sin que este tenga que hacer una solicitud es mediante **WebSockets**.

Otra es [Tecnología push](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnolog%C3%ADa_push) tal y como lo comentan los chicos en los comentarios.

Lo otro que puedes hacer es mediante un **setInterval** de javascript es preguntarle a servidor cada tantos segundos cual es el ultimo valor.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Eso de `...La única forma ... es mediante WebSockets` es **totalmente falso**. [En la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnolog%C3%ADa_push) tienes una lista: *Push*, *long polling*, ...

Comment: @Juanjo justo estaba por comentar lo mismo...

Comment: Gracias por el comentario ahí lo agregue a la respuesta para no dar información errónea a los próximos lectores.